# Fourier transform with the function in denominator

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to do a [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of this function

$$\frac{\bigtriangleup f(\textbf{x})}{1+f(\textbf{x})}$$

in terms of $\mathcal{F}(f(\textbf{x}))$. (Just like here $\mathcal{F}\left({\bigtriangleup f(\textbf{x})}\right)=-k^2\mathcal{F}(f)$)

The only solution I see is expand the denominator as series and then use [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). After that I get a lot of integrals in the answer.

So, is there ways to get more explicit answer?